# как динамически перечислить аргументы функции?

Tags: классы, функции, php7.3

пишу микросервис на `swoole` который держит в памяти класс (сторонний, написан не мной) и принимает POST запросы (swoole - аналогия Flask на python).

отправка запросов микросервису выглядит так:

`$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://127.0.0.1:9999");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);`

в обработчике получаю доступ к полям/методам таким способом:

`$MyClass->{$_POST["field"]}`

т.е. доступ к самим полям я могу получить указав его имя в `$data["field"]` при отправке запроса.

теперь нужно таким же (динамическим) способом вызывать методы с параметрами количество которых известно заранее, например метод с 3мя параметрами:

`$MyClass->{$_POST["method"]}($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)`

единственное что пришло мне в голову нагородить кучу `if` в которых определять сколько параметров необходимо функции (на основании данных в $`_POST`) и соответственно вызывать её отдельно в каждом блоке `if` с нужным количеством аргументов.

есть ли способы проще динамически указать количество аргументов функции зная их количество?

Answer (score 0):

проблема решается с помощью дополнительного поля в запросе которое указывает вариант использования и функции `call_user_func_array`, она принимает 2 аргумента - имя вызываемой функции либо метод класса в виде `[$class, 'mtehod']`, и ассоциативный массив каждый ключ которого будет являться самостоятельным аргументом.

пример:

`if($multy_args){
//метод с динамическим числом параметров, их количество - количество ключей в $dt
    $data = call_user_func_array([$MyClass->{$field}, $method], $dt);
}else{
//метод с 1м параметром
    $data = $MyClass->{$field}->{$method}($dt);
}`